# How to scale and set coordinates of MediaView?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I would like to embedd a video in my JavaFx 2.x scene and also resize it and relocate it to my needs. The problem I'm having is following. If I build a `MediaView` component and then translate X or Y coordinate, then the whole view is being **properly moved** like so:

```
MediaView mv = (...)
mv.setTranslateX(200);
mv.setTranslateY(200);
```

I could do a similar transformation with scaling property:

```
MediaView mv = (...)
mv.setScaleX(2);
mv.setScaleY(2);
```

which will **properly scale** `mv` instance two times in dimension.

However, the problem is when I combine those two translations. The `mv` instance is being scaled but it **always ends up in screen coordinates `(0,0)`**. This is of course incorrect behavior from my perspective.

I have also tried to wrap my `MediaView` component within some wrapper node, like `Group` and perform translations on this element. The behavior is the same.

**How can I properly move and scale `MediaView` component at the same time?**

Edit:

Here is my code, although I'm using here `ImageView`. This is irrelevant, however. After running this code, image will be placed at `(0,0)` instead of `(100,100)`.

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group();

        // Img's dimension is 200x200
        javafx.scene.image.Image img = new javafx.scene.image.Image("/home/bachman/projects/cs-player/src/main/resources/content.png");
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(img);
        root.getChildren().add(iv);

        // Move Image View
        iv.setTranslateX(100);
        iv.setTranslateY(100);

        // Scale Image View
        iv.setScaleX(2.0);
        iv.setScaleY(2.0);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setWidth(600);
        stage.setHeight(600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

Comment: can you, please, paste the code then you "combine those two translations".

Comment: I have added sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use setScaleX, setScaleY, scaling occurs from the center of the node.

If you want to translate by an amount in addition to scaling, you need to take the scaling expansion into account when you set the required translation values.  For example, if the node doubles in size (and you want to translate the node to a position relative to the upper left corner of the unscaled node), you need to translate by an additional half the node width and height.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.media.*;
import javafx.scene.transform.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TransformedVideo extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    final MediaPlayer oracleVid = new MediaPlayer(new Media("http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv"));
    final MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(oracleVid);
    mediaView.setFitWidth(320); mediaView.setFitHeight(240); mediaView.setPreserveRatio(false);

    mediaView.setTranslateX(mediaView.getFitWidth()  / 2 + 200); 
    mediaView.setTranslateY(mediaView.getFitHeight() / 2 + 200);
    mediaView.setScaleX(2); mediaView.setScaleY(2);

// alternative method of scaling and translating.    
//    mediaView.getTransforms().addAll(
//      new Translate(200, 200),
//      new Scale(2, 2)
//    );

    Group group = new Group(mediaView);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(group, 1250, 800));
    stage.show();

    oracleVid.play();

    System.out.println(group.getBoundsInParent());
  }
}
```

When performing multiple transforms on a node, rather than using the setScale/setTransform/setRotate methods, it is often easier to just supply a list of transforms to the getTransforms() method.

Comment: It appears that you are right. I will run some tests today and accept an answer if they will prove this claim.

Comment: Confirmed - the important part is indeed the fact, that scaling is done not from (0,0) as I anticipated, but from center of Node. Thx.

Comment: Is there any way to make a mediaview centralised when inside of a Pane?

Comment: Use a StackPane to center content cp.